# How to scan an array for certain information

Tags: java, arrays

I've been doing an MSc Software Development conversion course, the main language of which is Java, since the end of September. 
We have our first assessed practical coming and I was hoping for some guidance.

We have to create an array that will store 100 integers (all of which are between 1 and 10), which are generated by a random number generator, and then print out ten numbers of this array per line. For the second part, we need to scan these integers, count up how often each number appears and store the results in a second array.

I've done the first bit okay, but I'm confused about how to do the second. I have been looking through the scanner class to see if it has any methods which I could use, but I don't see any. Could anyone point me in the right direction - not the answer, but perhaps which library it comes from?

Code so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Practical4_Assessed 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Random numberGenerator = new Random ();

    int[] arrayOfGenerator = new int[100];

    for (int countOfGenerator = 0; countOfGenerator < 100; countOfGenerator++)
        arrayOfGenerator[countOfGenerator] = numberGenerator.nextInt(10);

    int countOfNumbersOnLine = 0;
    for (int countOfOutput = 0; countOfOutput < 100; countOfOutput++)
    {
        if (countOfNumbersOnLine == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("");
            countOfNumbersOnLine = 0;
            countOfOutput--;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(arrayOfGenerator[countOfOutput] + " ");
            countOfNumbersOnLine++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: You could use an `int[10]` array and store the occurence of each number (between 1 and 10) in the corresponding position in that array.

Comment: Thanks for the advice assylias. I was going to use an int[10] array, but I'm not sure how to scan the original array to see how often the numbers appears.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: It's just a loop. You look at each entry in the main array and use that entry as an index into your `int[10]` to increment that count.

Comment: @assylias: That's an answer, not just a comment. (Usually I'm posting the opposite of that statement! :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks - I'll have a go at that and post results later on. Thanks to both of you for very quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you get a random number, store it in an `int` variable then increment the corresponding bucket of the "counting array":

```
int[] countingArray = new int[10];
for (int countOfGenerator = 0; countOfGenerator < 100; countOfGenerator++) {
    // Get a number between 0 and 9 (inclusive); we'll add 1 to it in a moment
    int number = numberGenerator.nextInt(10);

    // Update your counts (array indexes start at 0, which is why we
    // haven't added to `number` yet)
    countingArray[number]++;

    // Store the actual number, which we add to because the assignment
    // is for 1-10, not 0-9
    arrayOfGenerator[countOfGenerator] = number + 1;
}
```

Now, `countingArray[0]` is how many `1`s you have, `countingArray[1]` is how many `2`s you have, etc. E.g., where `x` is 1 to 10 inclusive, `countingArray[x - 1]` is how many of number `x` you have.

Comment: Yeah. Depending on the wording of the assignment, it may not be acceptable to skip the "scan through the array" bit (even though in real life the above would be the better solution).

Comment: The assignment doesn't say anything about scanning the array - that was my bit. I get Grisha's solution below though probably more than this one. Where you have written getSomeRandomNumberBetween1And10() - what would I be writing in my program to correspond with the code? Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMartin I was trying to give you a hint only - I have amended to stick to your existing code.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Also note that `nextInt(10)` returns numbers between 0 and 9, so you need to add 1.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: As you can see, rather than counting them after-the-fact, assylias' approach is to count them as you generate them, which is more efficient than doing it after-the-fact. Grisha's answer shows how you would do that if you were given the array rather than generating it, but if you're generating it, assylias' approach would be more appropriate. Engineering is like that, full of trade-offs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any library, just loop over your array and count:

```
    for (int x : arrayOfGenerator)
        ar2[x]++;

    //test with
    for (int i=0; i<ar2.length; i++)
        System.out.println("num of "+i+" ="+ar2[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't know about the syntax used in your first for statement. Very helpful.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: It's called the ["enhanced for" statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) (in Java; most languages call it the "for each" loop, sometimes -- as in the case of C# -- literally using `foreach` as the keyword).